# Is there any way I can keep the browser away from requesting the same image each second?

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, jakarta-ee

My jsp page gets refreshed after each second. There are two images on page. One weighs 13 KB and other weighs 4 KB. Firefox doesn't load the images again and again but chrome keeps on loading the two images again and again. And it looks very bad ! Is there any way I can keep the browser from requesting the same image again and again ?

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX and refresh only the part of the page you need?

Comment: @svz I can't. Is there any way with java

Comment: why is there no way to use AJAX?

Comment: @KevinEsche I don't know AJAX. Also I want to implement this one simple thing.

Comment: and AJAX is the way to do it =). Just JSP can't do what you want.

Comment: @Steven that's it then ! Shall I delete this question now ?

Comment: based on this side http://www.coderanch.com/t/443223/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Frames-loading-refresh it says: 
`Don't be spending much of your time on this. I am pretty confident it is browser behavior in how it handles the iframe on refresh. I opened the code through FireFox, then I changed the URL in the file, saved, then refreshed the page. It proceeded to reload the original URL (prior to the refresh), then triggered the onLoad function loading the iframe with the new URL.`

So the whole thing is browser speficific. If you would like to have dynamic refreshes you should learn AJAX

Comment: It should be quite easy to learn how to refresh only part of a page using ajax. [Here](http://aleembawany.com/2005/09/01/ajax-instant-tutorial/) is a good tutorial to get you started.

Comment: @saplingPro is your page served via HTTPS? Do you have a proper `Cache-Control` header when serving your images?

Comment: @mtrbean http for now. No i do not have a Cache-Control header.

Comment: @KevinEsche I think you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set an appropriate `Expire` header and `Last-Modified` header. From [the maker of Chrome](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching):

> Recommendations
>
> - Set caching headers aggressively for all static resources. For all
>     cacheable resources, we recommend the following settings: Set Expires
>     to a minimum of one month, and preferably up to one year, in the
>     future. (We prefer Expires over Cache-Control: max-age because it is
>     is more widely supported.) Do not set it to more than one year in the
>     future, as that violates the RFC guidelines. If you know exactly when
>     a resource is going to change, setting a shorter expiration is okay.
>     But if you think it "might change soon" but don't know when, you
>     should set a long expiration and use URL fingerprinting (described
>     below). Setting caching aggressively does not "pollute" browser
>     caches: as far as we know, all browsers clear their caches according
>     to a Least Recently Used algorithm; we are not aware of any browsers
>     that wait until resources expire before purging them.
> - Set the Last-Modified date to the last time the resource was changed.
>     If the Last-Modified date is sufficiently far enough in the past,
>     chances are the browser won't refetch it.

If you are serving under HTTPS, you need to have properly signed certificate on your server otherwise Chrome wouldn't cache anything.

Answer (score 1):

based on [this side](http://coderanch.com/t/443223/HTML-CSS-JavaScript):

> Don't be spending much of your time on this. I am pretty confident it is browser behavior in how it handles the iframe on refresh. I opened the code through FireFox, then I changed the URL in the file, saved, then refreshed the page. It proceeded to reload the original URL (prior to the refresh), then triggered the onLoad function loading the iframe with the new URL.

So the whole thing is browser specific. If you would like to have dynamic refreshes you should learn AJAX

Answer (score 0):

A professional solution is to get the media-files from another server (ie facebook uses fbcdn instead of www) there you have always the full control over all caching mechanism in dedicated environment.

Another good solution is to use the **etag**-functionality ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag ), this must respect https-certificated as mtrbean's  suggested.

The last-modified date is also a good solution, use this in combination with "Pragma: no-cache".